# Application crashing on loading the last page of viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

Hi I have dynamic forms to be displayed in the app. The forms further contains sections(pages) I need to fetch questions for each page from the web service. For this I am getting the number of sections for each forms on the parent activity. From activity I am passing the list of pages of one form to the viewPager Adapter and from there we are creating number of pages dynamically based on the list coming from Activity by reusing same fragment. My application is crashing while creating the last page of the viewPager.

> Getting the forms data and the pages in each form

```
 private void getFormsList()
{
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = getProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDialog.show();

    RestClient.getInstanceWithToken(MainActivity.this, "", "https://rj-corp-survey-app.herokuapp.com/").getForms().enqueue(new Callback<GetFormsListResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GetFormsListResponse> call, Response<GetFormsListResponse> response) {
            GetFormsListResponse getFormsListResponse = response.body();

            if(getFormsListResponse != null && getFormsListResponse.equals("null") == false && getFormsListResponse.isSuccess() == true && getFormsListResponse.getCode() == 200)
            {
                formsArrayList = getFormsListResponse.getData().getForms();


                System.out.print("forms list>>>"+ formsArrayList);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getFormsListResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(formsArrayList != null && formsArrayList.size()>0)
                {
                    for(int i=0; i<formsArrayList.size(); i++)
                    {
                        formCode = formsArrayList.get(i).getFormShortCode();

                        formCodeList.add(formCode);

                        sectionsArrayList = formsArrayList.get(i).getSections();


                        if(i==0)
                        {
                            distributorFormId = formsArrayList.get(i).get_id();

                            for(int j=0; j<formsArrayList.get(i).getSections().size(); j++)
                            {
                                String distributorForm = formsArrayList.get(i).getSections().get(j).getSectionShortCode();
                                DistributorSectionNames.add(distributorForm);
                                String sectionId = formsArrayList.get(i).getSections().get(j).get_id();
                                distributorSectionIdList.add(sectionId);
                            }
                        }
                        if(i==1)
                        {
                            outletFormId = formsArrayList.get(i).get_id();

                            for(int j=0; j<formsArrayList.get(i).getSections().size(); j++)
                            {
                                String outletForm = formsArrayList.get(i).getSections().get(j).getSectionShortCode();
                                OutletSectionNames.add(outletForm);
                                String sectionId = formsArrayList.get(i).getSections().get(j).get_id();
                                outletSectionIdList.add(sectionId);
                            }
                        }
                        if(i==2)
                        {
                            spokeFormId = formsArrayList.get(i).get_id();

                            for(int j=0; j<formsArrayList.get(i).getSections().size(); j++)
                            {
                                String spokeForm = formsArrayList.get(i).getSections().get(j).getSectionShortCode();
                                SpokeSectionNames.add(spokeForm);
                                String sectionId = formsArrayList.get(i).getSections().get(j).get_id();
                                spokeSectionIdList.add(sectionId);
                            }
                        }


                        if(sectionsArrayList != null && sectionsArrayList.size()>0)
                        {
                            for(int j=0; j<sectionsArrayList.size(); j++)
                            {
                                sectionCode = sectionsArrayList.get(j).getSectionShortCode();
                                sectionCodeList.add(sectionCode);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Forms Present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            else if(getFormsListResponse != null && getFormsListResponse.equals("null") == false)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getFormsListResponse.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            populateData(formCodeList,distributorFormId, distributorSectionIdList);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GetFormsListResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("", "failure: " + t.getMessage());
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

> passing list of pages to adapter

```
private void populateData(ArrayList<String> formCodeList, String distributorFormId, ArrayList<String> distributorSectionIdList)
{
    ViewPager pager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new FormAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), formCodeList, distributorFormId, distributorSectionIdList));
}
```

> creating number of pages of each form dynamically by reusing same fragment

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return FormFragment.newInstance(position + 1, getCount(), sections.get(position),distributorFormId, distributorSectionIdList.get(position) );
    }
```

> newInsnce() body

```
public static FormFragment newInstance(int index, int total, String name, String distributorFormId, String distributorSectionId ) {
        FormFragment f = new FormFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(KEY_INDEX, index);
        args.putInt(KEY_TOTAL, total);
        args.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
        args.putString(KEY_FORM_ID, distributorFormId);
        args.putString(KEY_SECTION_ID, distributorSectionId);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }
```

> error log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ampersand.testdynamicforms, PID: 27738
   java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6494)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3109)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16525)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16525)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16525)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1630)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16525)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16525)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16525)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16525)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16525)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16525)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2358)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16525)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1962)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1159)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1341)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1046)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5660)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:9
```

Comment: Can you post the error logs !

Comment: Provide logcat out

Comment: posted the error log kindly check !

Comment: Which line the app crashses?